Image analysis with MATLAB: transforming an image taken at an angle back to direct view
I have a series of photographs taken at an angle, like this:

What I would like to do is "straighten" these photographs into direct view:

The above examples are taken from this Photoshop tutorial.
As the video linked to shows, there are numerous tutorials on the Internet showing ways to do this using Photoshop, Lightroom, and other applications, but I would like to know if there's a way to code this using MATLAB. And out of curiosity, does this have something to do with cross-ratios?

the term is "homography". I've added some tags. -- cross-ratios? maybe... it's all projective geometry. image plane (sensor plane), plane in the scene (facade of the building)

https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estgeotform2d.html with "projective" is what you want for working with homographies.
